# END is not working in insert function of tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

When I click on button to populate the data in list it show following:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Haseeb Bhai\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

File "E:\Python Development\Book-Store\intermediate.py", line 17, in view_command
    front_end.book_list.insert(END, row)

NameError: name 'END' is not defined
```

I'm calling it with this code:

```
tkinter.Listbox.insert(END, row)
```

One more thing here is I want to add the new row at the start of the list. I hope passing 0 as the index will override the previous first value so what should be the index arg to insert the row at the start of the list.

Comment: How are you importing tkinter? Regardless, I recommend using the string constant `"end"`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I wasn't importing tkinter in current file. I got it. Thanks man for your time. Do you know how to add element in start of list?

Answer (score 3):

You need to refer to that module-level variable with its appropriate, qualified name, which depends on how you imported Tkinter. In this case:

```
tkinter.Listbox.insert(tkinter.END, row)
```

Comment: Oh yes, Now I got it. Thanks man. :)

Comment: Please help me on the second part of this question too. Thanks!